# Sequencing in odoo 10

Tags: sequence, odoo-10

I am trying to create a sequence in odoo here is my xml file

```
<record model="ir.sequence" id="connection_sequence_id">
        <field name="name">New Connections Sequence</field>
        <field name="code">ftth.connection</field>
        <field name="prefix">FTTH</field>
        <field name="padding">6</field>
        <field name="company_id" eval="False" />
 </record>
```

I have created a field for it in my .py file

```
my_seq = fields.Char(string="sequence", default=lambda self: _('New'))
```

and overiddeen the create function by using the following code

```
 @api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals:
        vals['my_seq'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('ftth.connection') or _('New')
        result = super(NewConnections, self).create(vals)
        return result
```

but my code is not generating a sequence instead it gives ftth.connection.(sequence number).what might be wrong with my code.please assist

Answer (score 1):

use super to customize your create function, this an example:

```
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals:
           seq = self.env['ir.sequence']
           vals['my_seq'] = seq.next_by_code('ftth.connection') or _('New')
        return super(ObjectName, self).create(values)
```